# Connection to Podio API failed: [92] when uploading files

Tags: laravel, file-upload, multipartform-data, podio

Connected the podio file upload to attach images to item. Started getting the "Connection to Podio API failed: [92]" error. Before everything worked fine. Is it a problem on my side or on Podio's side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podio does not define `CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION` variable in it's curl requests and therefore leaving the decision to curl client to decide.

in your case I guess cURL chooses HTTP2 version for unknown reasons ( might be due to SSL implementation ) and according to my experience with Podio, PodioFile::upload breaks when HTTP2 is used.

To solve the issue you would need to force Podio to use HTTP1.1 , This should fix your issue :

1. inside  lib/Podio.php look for `curl_setopt(self::$ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);`
2. just beneath it add `curl_setopt(self::$ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);`

Tip: do consider upgrading to the latest version of the package `podio-community/podio-php` before modifying the code and Good luck.

Comment: Thanks! but now I get a 52 error, I found another thread which said it's because it shouldn't just be the directory but also with filename but I'm using 'enctype="multipart/form-data"' which is why I don't have the file location. How would I solve this?